# AngularJS use two way data binding to display image in img element tag as source?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, data-binding, two-way

I am making a http request that returns a url to an image. I would like to display the image in my html page. Is there a way to do this? I idea of what I want to do is (this doesn't work but..) img src={{result.imageurl}}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you have to use `ng-src="{{result.imageurl}}"`

See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSrc